# ui-router global state with "main view"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

can someone please point me to an example of managing global states for ui-router?
i'm trying to implement a general site template that contains on all pages a header and a footer, with a main view that changes along with nested views within that view.

`<div ui-view="header">` should appear on all pages, has its own controller.
`<div ui-view>main view` that holds the different "pages" and nested views
`<div ui-view="footer">` should appear on all pages, has its own controller.

i will try to elaborate, this is my current state with angulars routing:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
  </div> 
</body>
```

i would like to migrate to ui-router, but cannot achieve the same.
i need the header and the footer on all pages and an ui-view as main content that will hold all views/nested vies and stats

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That will definitely work for you.  You'll just need to make sure it's `ui-view` insteadl of `ng-view`. Here's what I'm using now on a similar app:

```
<div ng-include src="'app/templates/nav.html'" id="global-nav"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
<footer ng-include src="'app/templates/footer.html'"></footer>
```

Comment: Ui-view seems to offer multiple named views. There should be a way for there to be a "layout" state.

Comment: Yep, you can definitely do that as well.  On an app example that only has one changing view, I think it's easier to keep it out of ui-router and just add an ng-controller for static views.

Comment: True. That's what I've been doing. But I'd like to be able to achieve this via states. Call it an experiment in architecture. I expanded the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104893/angular-ui-router-how-to-create-a-layout-state